# X509_REQ_sign using engine

Tags: openssl, tpm

I am trying to sign a csr using X509_REQ_sign with a TPM engine (tpm2tss). 
I can accomplish a non-engine request signature using the following code:

```
    X509_REQ* req = NULL;
    unsigned char* reqBytes = NULL;
    char* csrString = NULL;
    if((req = X509_REQ_new()) && \
            X509_REQ_set_subject_name(req, subject) && \
            X509_REQ_set_pubkey(req, keyPair) && \
            X509_REQ_sign(req, keyPair, EVP_sha256()))  
    {
        int reqLen = i2d_X509_REQ(req, NULL);
        reqBytes = malloc(reqLen);
        unsigned char* tempReqBytes = reqBytes;
        i2d_X509_REQ(req, &tempReqBytes);   
        csrString = base64_encode(reqBytes, (size_t)reqLen, false, NULL);
    }
    free(reqBytes);
    X509_REQ_free(req);
    return csrString;
```

What is the proper way to change the function EVP_sha256() from the standard Envelope to the tpm2tss engine?  The keyPair can only be used in the TPM module (as it exists as an encrypted BLOB on the file system).  The engine knows this, and will decrypt the BLOB before signing the request with the private key.

Comment: keyPair (the EVP_PKEY) specifes the engine; if it was correctly created for an engine-based key it should already do so.

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085.  The key was initially created using tpm2-genkey to store an encrypted key on the filesystem.  To load that into EVP_PKEY, I used the tpm2tss_tpm2data_read() command to populate a TPM2_DATA structure and then a tpm2tss_rsa_makekey() to convert the data structure to an EVP_PKEY.  Is that the correct sequence?

Comment: I don't use that lib/engine so I can't say for sure (or test) but it sounds like the right kind of process. If you have (compiled with) symbols, I would use the debugger to look at `keyPair` and see if the `engine` field is nonnull and when indirected contains appropriate-looking values.